# Hashing DWG files - empty models don't receive the same hash code

Tags: c#, hashcode, autocad, dwg

I want to use a hash function (SHA1) to determine whether two DWG models from AutoCAD 2018 are identical or not. To test if this works, I created two empty dwg files and used the SHA1 function in c# (System.Security.Cryptography.sha1) to calculate the hash code.

I was expecting resulting codes to be identical, since I only started two new empty models and then saved them directly. The only data which should differ is the name and date & time of creation (all meta data, which shouldn't play a role for the algorithm). Yet, the result was two different hash codes.

So I looked into the byte array of the two files. The only thing I could get out of it (a lot of lines which I could not interpret in any way), was that some of the meta data as date and time of creation is written in the byte array. Therefore the two files are actually not identical, eventhough the models are. So there will always be a different hash code for all hashed DWG models.

Does anyone know of this problem or a work-around for my issue?

Code used to calculate hash:

```
static void GetFileHash(string filePath)
        {
            var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            byte[] hashByte = sha1.ComputeHash(bArray);
            string hashCode = BitConverter.ToString(hashByte);

            //save file path, hash and byte array to text file
            string[] lines = { filePath, hashCode, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bArray)};               System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\HashTest.txt", lines);
        }
```

Snippet of the byte array in which the saving time and date is captured:

A p p I n f o D a t a L i s t      �H��

> M��ρ��P� 2 2 . 0 . 4 9 . 0 . 0   ���%�דI����(o��r A u t o d e s k   D W G .     T h i s   f i l e   i s   a   T r u s t e d   D W G   l a s t   s a v e d   b y   a n   A u t o d e s k   a p p l i c a t i o n   o r   A u t o d e s k   l i c e n s e d   a p p l i c a t i o n .   �����Oh�� +'��J< p r o p _ s e t   f m t _ i d = " { f 2 9 f 8 5 e 0 - 4 f f 9 - 1 0 6 8 - a b 9 1 - 0 8 0 0 2 b 2 7 b 3 d 9 } " > < p r o p   i d = " 8 " > < s t r i n g > M a x < / s t r i n g > < / p r o p > < p r o p   i d = " 1 0 " > < d a t e t i m e > 2 0 2 0 - 0 7 - 1 4 T 0 9 : 5 1 : 3 3 < / d a t e t i m e > < / p r o p > < p r o p   i d = " 2 5 8 " > < s t r i n g > A u t o C A D   2 0 1 8 < / s t r i n g > < / p r o p > < p r o p   i d = " 2 5 9 " > < s t r i n g > O . 4 9 . 0 . 0 < / s t r i n g > < / p r o p > < p r o p   i d = " 1 2 " > < d a t e t i m e > 2 0 2 0 - 0 7 - 1 4 T 0 9 : 5 1 : 2 9 < / d a t e t i m e > < / p r o p > < / p r o p _ s e t >   ���Q�βD����;��D� " < P r o d u c t I n f o r m a t i o n   n a m e   = \ " A u t o C A D \ "   b u i l d _ v e r s i o n = \ " O . 4 9 . 0 . 0 ( x 6 4 ) \ "   r e g i s t r y _ v e r s i o n = \ " 2 2 . 0 \ "   i n s t a l l _ i d _ s t r i n g = \ " A C A D - 1 0 0 1 : 4 0 9 \ "   r e g i s t r y _ l o c a l e I D = \ " 1 0 3 3 \ " > "

Comment: "identical files don't receive the same hash code" and the fact you found that files are different don't align. Please [edit] question with what you actually want to achieve. Ideally you'd show code that you use to say that content of two files is the same (so one can suggest what to use to compute hash or some other comparison)

Comment: Only possible work-around seems to be for your code to intelligently exclude the differences that it does not care about.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I also thought about that possibility. Have to do some tests to identitfy the relevant lines.

Comment: The part that explains how you want to compare is still missing - code you've shown is for byte-level equality which is clearly not what you are asking about.  Maybe you should do some research on how do you actually want to compare DWG files and clarify that in the post?

Comment: `all meta data, which shouldn't play a role for the algorithm` What makes you say that they don't impact the hash code / contents?

Comment: @mjwills I thought that hash algorithms don't take the meta data in consideration and only the content of the file? The problem with DWG files seems, that some of its meta data is contained directly in the content

Answer (score 0):

When a new empty model is created, it will add some stuff for you like a layer "0", the model space and the paper space.  Which will be added to the cad database table record and assign some id's which will be different no matter how many new model your create.

For example. when you look into the data assigned to layer "0" of 2 new empty models it will look like that:

```
// Layer "0" from Model 1
"((-1,(2956860066048))(0,LAYER)(5,10)(102,{ACAD_XDICTIONARY)(360,(2956924193344))(102,})(330,(2956860065824))(100,AcDbSymbolTableRecord)(100,AcDbLayerTableRecord)
(2,0)(70,0)(62,7)(6,Continuous)(290,1)(370,-3)(390,(2956860066032))(347,(2956860067552))(348,(0)))"

// Layer "0" from Model 2
"((-1,(2991422834944))(0,LAYER)(5,10)(102,{ACAD_XDICTIONARY)(360,(2991422843456))(102,})(330,(2991422834720))(100,AcDbSymbolTableRecord)(100,AcDbLayerTableRecord)
(2,0)(70,0)(62,7)(6,Continuous)(290,1)(370,-3)(390,(2991422834928))(347,(2991422836448))(348,(0)))"
```

Those are quite different and will be in the .dwg binary content you are comparing the hash which is unknown what it stores inside it. In order for the hash to be the same you would need to copy paste the file.

A workaround could be to save the file into dxf format instead which are human readable so you can ignore some data to consider the files identical.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to create a byte array that I could actually read. It turns out, that even the time spend in the drawing is saved... Do you know what caused the difference in your example?

Comment: Yes, everything inside a DWG act as a database entry, the model, the layer are too. When you create a new drawing it creates new entries for you and assign them unique id making them different.

But if you use the DXF format, those id's don't seems to have any influence so you could ignore them. The time and some coordinate which seems to be the view center are the main data which seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere does any sort of a hash enter the picture, so to speak. You don't care what's *in* the DWG file, you care that it looks the same!

In general this can't work, unless the file you're hashing is in the canonical form. That'd also mean that such a canonical form has to exist - not a given at all! I don't know offhand about whether there is a canonical form of DWG, or whether it's even an easy problem to create one, such that visually identical results would have same DWG form. In general, the answer to this is a solid *no*.

The summary of the problem is that files that appear visually identical when rendered at a particular resolution may have an extremely large number of possible permutations in their DWG representation - in practice you could consider it infinite.

So, you cannot hash the DWG file itself, not even if you had a DWG library that could read the primitives - you'd need to use a computational geometry library to attempt to process the data into some canonical form.

The best you can do with limited resources is to rasterize both DWGs, and then run a visual comparison between the bitmaps thus obtained, at a reasonable printout resolution (say 600-1200dpi). The comparison algorithm should be insensitive to common pitfalls such as different "hardness" of line edges, but it should be sensitive to changes that alter the visual meaning of the document - this may not be straightforward either, and you'd need to look for a library/package that can do such comparisons for you, specifically targeted for line art and not photographs (!!). The files can also have different absolute coordinates for the primitives (due to transformations yielding same output), and slightly different scaling.

Thus, in most likelihood, you'd need to first visually align the bitmaps (there are algorithms for this that can have e.g. translation, scaling and rotation as degrees of freedom), then re-rasterize the second image in the pair taking the alignment into account, and then run a visual comparison, and produce some sort of a "score". You could also highlight the differences and display them on screen.

Comment: Will look into your suggestion using a canonical form! Is the method of running a visual comparison also possible when using a 3D model?

Comment: It is possible but you'll be comparing solids, and that's a whole another kettle of fish. It's computationally intensive and at the forefront of research still. There are some solutions, but it's not as easy as comparing bitmaps.